# Get String widthPoint in iText with Style = BOLD

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, font-size

I am using both `BaseFont.getWidthPoint()` and `Chunk.getWidthPoint()` to calculate the String size. I found out that set Style to `"BOLD"` doesn't affect the result in both functions. I assume `"BOLD"` will increase the size of the String. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
String ls = "test length lalalalalala";
Font laFont = new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12);
laFont.setStyle("BOLD");

BaseFont bf_helv = laFont.getCalculatedBaseFont(false);
float width_helv = bf_helv.getWidthPoint(ls, 12);

System.out.println("------size----------" + width_helv);

Chunk laC = new Chunk(ls); 
laC.setFont(laFont);
System.out.println("------size C----------" + laC.getWidthPoint());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Font.html#setStyle(java.lang.String)) and [the source](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/Font.java#l566) `setStyle(string)` takes one or more of six possible values:

```
normal, bold, italic, oblique, underline, line-through
```

The check, however, is done case-sensitive, so you need to change your `BOLD` to just `bold`

Answer (score 1):

```
laFont.setStyle("BOLD");
```

should be

```
laFont.setStyle("bold");
```

In order not to have issues with upper/lower case, you should use the constants provided in the [FontStyle](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Font.FontStyle.html) enum:

```
laFont.setStyle(FontStyle.BOLD);
```